# Convert the lambda function to a regular function

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I am looking to convert the lambda function to a regular function e.g. def convert_time(). Can anyone help?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
from durations_nlp import Duration


df['Total Hours'] = df['Projects'].apply(lambda x: sum(map(float,str(Duration(x).to_hours()).split(','))))

## Value in Projects df are in this format "1h,2h 30m,15m,20m,45m,35m"
```

Comment: convert_time = lambda x: sum(map(float,str(Duration(x).to_hours()).split(',')))

Comment: def convert_time(x): return sum(map(float,str(Duration(x).to_hours()).split(',')))

Comment: Just move it, its simple. Please understand what is lambda function https://towardsdatascience.com/lambda-functions-with-practical-examples-in-python-45934f3653a8

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the same argument passed to lambda, then just return the expression that is inside the lambda:

```py
def convert_time(x):
    return sum(map(float,str(Duration(x).to_hours()).split(',')))
```

`lambda x: sum(map(float,str(Duration(x).to_hours()).split(',')))` means, argument is `x`, and return value is the expression `sum(map(float,str(Duration(x).to_hours()).split(',')))`

Then you can just replace the lambda function by the newly created function:

```py
df['Total Hours'] = df['Projects'].apply(convert_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [`lambdas`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) are more restricted in what is allowed inside (i.e. everything legal inside lambda is legal inside `def` also), it is easy to convert `lambda` to `def`, in this case equivalent of

```
lambda x: sum(map(float,str(Duration(x).to_hours()).split(',')))
```

is

```
def convert_time(x):
    return sum(map(float,str(Duration(x).to_hours()).split(',')))
```